# Delay in serial communication using jssc

Tags: java, jssc

I am using `jssc` for serial port communication with simulator which I made. The thing is whenever server requests for a device from my simulator I encounter a delay as device in my simulator replies after some time, not exactly after the request. For replying to the request packet I am using `jssc` method `writeBytes()` inside the serial event listener which is:

```
SerialPort.writeBytes(packet);
```

and the packet is less than 20 bytes and also I am checking my serial event that is

```
if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){}
```

Can you guys help me out to reduce this delay so that simulator device replies just after the request? Here is a piece of code-

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
{           
    if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0)
    {
        byte Server_PacketByte;
        try {
            Server_PacketByte = receiver_Port.readBytes(1)[0];
            byte[] form_packet = PacketFormation(Server_PacketByte);// for adding bytes to make packet
            if(form_packet == null)
            {
                return;                 
            }

            for(Device d : devices)
            {
                if(form_packet != null)
                {
                    d.processPacket(form_packet);// in the list of devices I have all the information of device and also reply packet
                }
            }               
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

inside processPacket()

```
if (packet.equals(REQUEST))
         {
            receiver_Port.writeBytes(device.getReply());
         }
```

Comment: First off, are you sure the call is being executed when you expect it to be?

Comment: Yeah I am sure. The call is executing the time I captured request packet but it's replying after some time and by the time reply comes server creates 2 to 3 further request.

Comment: Well, that's to be expected with inter-system communication; you won't get immediate responses. Things take time to compute, encode, and transmit over the line.

Comment: If you're expecting your simulated system to be faster, then you should ask (and give more details) about that instead.

Comment: So is there any way to overcome it?

Comment: Yes and no; without knowing how the simulated system works in greater detail, we can't just make it go faster; optimization is difficult, and in some cases, close to impossible. What does the simulated system you're calling into do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think what's happening with your system is that the response from your simulator back to the server is taking too long, or the server requests are too close together to be useful. If your simulator's response to the server takes too long, then it may disregard or ignore your server's subsequent requests, and your server may handle this by either ignoring the response (since it's for a request it already gave up on) or worse, thinking the response to request #1 is the response to request #3 (which may have had different parameters, and would therefore be invalid).

[image: timing diagram]

The solution for this is to either have the server wait a longer amount of time for the response before trying another request, or to somehow reduce the amount of time the simulator needs to respond to the server's request.

If you're just doing an "is device connected" or "get device info"-style request of the device, or one that doesn't require real-time responses, you could have your simulator do that on its own (via a request loop on a separate thread or something) and cache the response, and just hand it back when requested from the server. However, you'd have to make sure that it gets aborted when a real-time request comes through, so it's almost more complicated than necessary.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I don't think that it's your serial communication that's experiencing an undue delay, because **SERIAL COMMUNICATION IS SLOW**. I think you haven't considered that fact in your design, and you're expecting all communication for your potentially large number of devices to complete within a certain time frame. In addition, each device may take a variable amount of time to deliver a response back over serial; some of these may not even have flow control implemented properly, resulting in occasional delays or, in rare cases, delivery failures.

You should have some other thread in your Simulator be requesting updates from devices periodically and storing them in a table. That way, when a request comes in from the Server that asks about all devices, their information is already there, and can be packaged and delivered back to the server without the need for serial communication.

Comment: Assuming that we can't do anything with server... So how can we achieve a solution on simulator side because I think the methods `writeBytes()` and `readBytes()` are taking too much time. I will share some piece of code with you and also for second and third request, a reply is there and that is also late.

Comment: In the code that you posted, do you need to iterate across all Devices? How many devices are connected to the Simulator at a time?

Comment: Yes I am iterating whole process across all the devices instance and at a time I have to use more than 100 devices but till now I used only 10 and still delay was there that is sometimes it shows 9 devices and sometime 5 or 1, it varies.

Comment: I also tried it using threads and synchronized them also, but still the problem is same.

Comment: Hey @Shotgun do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Let me get this straight: Your command is looking to get info from *every* device in one request, and it's expecting it to be within a certain timeframe? I thought you were only requesting info from a *single* device per request. Your approach would have to be done via caching the device info on the simulator and refreshing it periodically, if you want to stick to the original timing requirements from the server.

Comment: Thing is I already generated packets while creating devices instance before starting serial event so that it can reduce some delay. So now during serial event it will just read the incoming request packets and send the reply packets which are already associated with each device. Now what do you think whether `java` and its library is causing this delay due to reading and writing packets or not?

Comment: I'm assuming that your server is communicating via network packets to your simulator; correct me if I'm wrong. If that's the case, and you already have the packet data present and can just transmit that back, then you're not messing with serial at all, are you?

Comment: Unless of course you have serial updates happening on a separate thread on the Simulator, and it's blocking the thread which is handling the response to the Server.

Comment: Yes server is communicating with simulator via network packets. Now when serial event starts every device is replying with these packets. After the serial event starts port will remain open to the server for reading the packets and then after the formation of request packet a thread starts which recognizes the request packet and replies back reply packet based on device instance it carries. Now I think `java` is responsible for this delay and I have to switch to `C` or `C++`. If you have any suggestion then please help me out.